# tf.zeros doesn't return a 1D tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to duplicate a tensor across a new axis, like this:

```
original_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
made_copies_tensor = tf.tile(original_tensor, 5)
final_result = tf.reshape([5,5])
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 650, in with_rank
raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape () must have rank 1
```

In the documentation it says the way I wrote tf.constant is supposed to have it return a 1D tensor but when I checked its shape with get_shape(), it has (5,) as its shape. I tried reshaping it but nothing changed.

Why am I getting this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "5" parameter has shape `()` but needs to have rank 1

```
original_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
made_copies_tensor = tf.tile(original_tensor, [5])
sess.run(made_copies_tensor)
```